# Find columns that contains numbers in strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that has columns with numbers, but these numbers are represented as strings. I want to find these columns automatically, without telling which column should be numeric. How can I do this in pandas?

Comment: If you only have either strings or numbers, you can do `df.apply(lambda col: col.astype("int64", errors="ignore"))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise `contains` from pandas

```
>>> df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('.*[0-9].*', regex=True)]
```

The regex can be modified to accomodate a wide range of patterns you want to search

Answer (score 0):

You can first filter using `pd.to_numeric` and then `combine_first` with original column:

```
df['COL_NAME'] = pd.to_numeric(df['COL_NAME'],errors='coerce').combine_first(df['COL_NAME'])
```